# How to align form in the middle of a parent div?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

When you hover over shopping list, it should expand to show several items and the total price. I wish to have the form be in the middle of the cart item. For example, Qty form is in the middle of Chloe and  $14,200. Please help me figure this out. If there is an easier way to put an input box for quantity, please let me know.

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}


/* Styles the list */

ul.breadcrumb {
  padding-top: 16px;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 60px;
}


/* Display items side by side */

ul.breadcrumb li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 15px;
}


/* Add a > symbol before/behind each list item */

ul.breadcrumb li+li:before {
  padding: 8px;
  color: #800020;
  content: ">";
}


/* Add color to all links inside the list */

ul.breadcrumb li a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.logo {
  max-width: 130px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 35px;
}

.header-heart-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 275px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.expand {
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 5%;
  width: 9%;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2.4%;
  right: 3.4%;
  color: black;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.expand:hover {
  height: 200px;
  width: 26vw;
  z-index: 10;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.cart-row {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}

.left-aligned {
  float: left;
}

.left-aligned-bold {
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

.center-aligned {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.right-aligned {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}

.line {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 5px 40px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: black;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
  color: #800020;
}

a {
  color: black;
}

.intro {
  margin-left: 10%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 45%;
}

.home-heading {
  font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 90px;
}

.intro-title {
  font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.intro-desc {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

.product-box {
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fafafa;
  height: 300px;
  max-width: 250px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.product-thumbnail {
  max-width: 230px;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 290px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 5px;
}

.product-page-box {
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin-left: 250px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  background: #fafafa;
  height: 540px;
  max-width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.product-page-thumbnail {
  max-width: 360px;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 5px;
}

.wrap {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 30px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.box {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.add-wishlist {
  margin-top: -300px;
  padding-left: 205px;
  position: absolute;
}

.product-heart-icon {
  display: flex;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  padding: 5px;
}

.text {
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  color: black;
  line-height: 1em;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.transparentbtn {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: gray;
  border-style: solid;
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  margin-top: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 35px;
  width: 100%;
}

.footer-col {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.footer-col h4 {
  font-size: 17px;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}

.footer-col ul li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.footer-col ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.footer-col ul li a {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: black;
  display: block;
}

.footer-col .social-links a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: black;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.footer-col .social-links a:hover {
  color: #24262b;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}


/*responsive*/

@media(max-width: 767px) {
  .footer-col {
    width: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 574px) {
  .footer-col {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

#header-wishlist {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 215px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

#header-cart {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#quantity-input {
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

#checkout-btn {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}


/* Here, product-name is the brand */

#product-name {
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

#product-description {
  font-size: 15px;
}

#product-price {
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}


/* Here, product-name is the brand */

#product-page-name {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 88px;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

#product-page-description {
  font-size: 18px;
}

#product-page-price {
  padding-top: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

#product-page-inventory {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

#dropdownMenuButton {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: grey;
  border-style: solid;
  color: black;
}

#productPageWishlist {
  min-width: 300px;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin-bottom: 13px;
}

#productPageCart {
  margin-left: 33px;
  font-size: 18px;
  min-width: 140px;
}

#limited-stock {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Elysian</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <img src="assets/white logo.png" class="logo" alt="logo">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <a href="#" class="header-heart-icon"><i class ="fa fa-heart-o"></i></a>
        <p id="header-wishlist"><a href="#">Wishlist</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="expand">
        <p id="header-cart">Shopping List</p>
        <div class="cart-row">
          <div class="left-aligned">Chloé</div>
          <div class="center-aligned">
            <input type="quantity" class="form-control" id="quantity-input" placeholder="Qty">
          </div>
          <div class="right-aligned">$14,200</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cart-row">
          <div class="left-aligned">Aquazzura</div>
          <div class="right-aligned">$4,425</div>
        </div>
        <hr class="line">
        <div class="cart-row">
          <div class="left-aligned-bold">TOTAL</div>
          <div class="right-aligned">$18,625</div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" id="checkout-btn">Check Out</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add the hover to shopping list-->
  </header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="clothes.html">Clothing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="shoes.html">Shoes</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="bags.html">Bags</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="intro">
    <h5 class="home-heading">New in: handpicked daily from the world's best brands</h5>
  </div>

  <div class="wrap">

    <div class="box">
      <div class="product-box">
        <a href="acne-studios.html"><img src="assets/Clothing/Acne Studios abstract-print T-shirt.png" class="product-thumbnail" alt="Acne Studios"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="add-wishlist">
        <a href="#" class="product-heart-icon"><i class ="fa fa-heart-o"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <!-- Here, product-name is the brand -->
        <h5 id="product-name"><a href="acne-studios.html">Acne Studios</a></h5>
        <p id="product-description">abstract-print T-shirt</p>
        <p id="product-price"> HK$2,100</p>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Add to Cart</button>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <div class="product-box">
        <a href="aquazurra.html"><img src="assets/Shoes/Aquazzura Saint Honore 50mm ankle boots.png" class="product-thumbnail" alt="Aquazzura"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="add-wishlist">
        <a href="#" class="product-heart-icon"><i class ="fa fa-heart-o"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <h5 id="product-name"><a href="aquazurra.html">Aquazzura</a></h5>
        <p id="product-description">Saint Honore 50mm ankle boots</p>
        <p id="product-price">HK$4,425</p>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Add to Cart</button>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <div class="product-box">
        <a href="chloé.html"><img src="assets/Bags/Chloé small Woody leather tote bag.png" class="product-thumbnail" alt="Chloé"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="add-wishlist">
        <a href="#" class="product-heart-icon"><i class ="fa fa-heart-o"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <h5 id="product-name"><a href="chloé.html">Chloé</a></h5>
        <p id="product-description">small Woody leather tote bag</p>
        <p id="product-price">HK$14,200</p>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Add to Cart</button>
    </div>

  </div>

  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="footer-col">
          <h4>Customer Service</h4>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Orders and delivery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Payment and pricing</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-col">
          <h4>About Elysian</h4>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Investors</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Elysian partner boutiques</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-col">
          <h4>Discounts and membership</h4>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Affiliate program</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Refer a friend</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Elysian membership</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-col">
          <h4>Follow us</h4>
          <div class="social-links">
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ive made it work here, with css added at the bottom of the css part. I would boild your layout using flexbox or grid. This is a good guide to Flexbox: https://www.joshwcomeau.com/css/interactive-guide-to-flexbox/ or watch Kevin Powell on Youtube :

https://codepen.io/plant996/pen/NWJXaNw

```
      <div class="cart-row-stack">
         <div >Chloé</div>
      <div >
        <input type="quantity" class="form-control" id="quantity- 
        input" placeholder="Qty">
      </div>
      <div>$14,200</div>
    </div>



    .cart-row-stack {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
     }
```

Comment: When I tried your code, the input form isn't in the middle of the div. Instead, it's justified with equal space between each text. However, when I have several items in my shopping cart, this might mean that the Qty forms aren't perfectly aligned. Please help. @Santi

Comment: Ah you can try to put a fixed width on the first column.
See here https://codepen.io/plant996/pen/BabYoWO